# Large internal memory allocation in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I created a python package to build initial topologies for simulations. Basically, to create such topologies, the user makes a pool of objects and then adds other objects into it. Currently, when many objects are added (> 100000), the memory consumption goes through the roof. I tracked this with tracemalloc:

```
import tracemalloc
tracemalloc.start()
sn1 = tracemalloc.take_snapshot()
object_pool.add_objects(object_to_add, N = 100)
sn2 = tracemalloc.take_snapshot()
ts = sn2.compare_to(sn1, 'lineno')
for stat in ts[:10]: print(stat)
```

This yields the following:

```
<__array_function__ internals>:6: size=4932 KiB (+4932 KiB), count=200 (+200), average=24.7 KiB
/usr/lib/python3.7/copy.py:237: size=644 KiB (+644 KiB), count=4554 (+4554), average=145 B
/usr/lib/python3.7/copy.py:169: size=190 KiB (+190 KiB), count=1388 (+1388), average=140 B
/usr/lib/python3.7/copyreg.py:88: size=103 KiB (+103 KiB), count=1500 (+1500), average=70 B
```

So the main memory load is from `__array_function__ internals`. Under the hood, add_objects creates a copy of object_to_add and adds it to the pool. These objects tend to be fairly complicated. Interestingly, changing numpy from version 1.17 to 1.18 reduced the amount of memory used by `__array_function__ internals` by a factor of 10.

My questions are: how does `__array_function__ internals` work and how do I reduce the amount of memory used by it ? IIs the only option reducing the amount of numpy arrays used ?

EDIT: The package in question is hoobas: https://bitbucket.org/NUaztec/hoobas/src/master/
The object pool is a builder, which the objects added are Composites. They contain numpy arrays for positions only (floats). To fully reproduce the behavior:

```
import hoobas
box = hoobas.SimulationDomain.EmptyCube(10.0)
object_to_add = hoobas.LinearChain.GenericPolymer(2)
object_pool = hoobas.Build.HOOMDBuilder(box)
object_pool.add_N_ext_obj(object_to_add, 100)
```

Comment: `__array_function__` is (part of) the basic array creator.  It's part of the compiled numpy code, and not something that we normally fiddle with.  I'm not seeing anything in the https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.18.0-notes.html about memory use improvements, but a search of the pull requests may give us more information.    The memory use of an array is fixed by the number of elements and `dtype`.  But the number and size of temporary buffers might change with code improvements.

Comment: "the user makes a pool of objects and then adds other objects into it.".  What are these objects and pool?  Python lists, custom classes, large numeric arrays, object dtype arrays?  Exploring the memory use of a few large arrays is quite different from the use of many smaller ones.

Comment: `__array_function__` reference: https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.classes.html?highlight=array_function#numpy.class.__array_function__

Comment: Without more information on `object_pool.add_objects` I don't think we can help you.  `__array_function__` gets called lots of times, but the average array size isn't that large.  `copy` is called a lot more, but it probably just makes new object references, not new objects.  Are you using a custom `ndarray` subclass?  Or lots of `object` dtype arrays?

Comment: The numpy arrays are floats, and in the example, only 3 x 2. Otherwise the pool contains lists and graphs. The pool contains an aggregated array and the 3x2 array refers to the aggregated array.

Comment: Also, the memory used by ```__array_function__``` doesn't show up in the heap (as reported by heapy).

Comment: @hpaulj Is there any way I can track where they are allocated in the code ?